# Copy Database schema in text file

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

My goal is to export the Database schema of a Database using `SQL MAnagement Studio`

From `SQL MS` if you right click on DB and select : *"Script DAtabase-> as create to"*

the tables of the DB do not get created in query window.

- Is there any other operation in `SQL MS` which satisfies my goal?
- If not how can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database class has method Script() which is doing exactly what you are looking for.